# Not getting auto suggesion while using swift class data into objective class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, targets

I have multiple target in my project. I have added productName-Swift.h in my objective c file.I am not getting suggestions in objective class for swift class still I am able to call some method of swift class but some gives error.

Swift Method :

```
func drawCircle(WithList arrCircle :NSMutableArray, withCoordinates lon :Float, latitude lat: Float,OnGlobe map:MKMapView)
```

Calling in Objective C

```
[object drawCircleWithList:arrCircles withCoordinates:longi latitude:lat onGlobe:globeController];
```

Can anyone help me out of this issue.

Comment: you need to be aware of adding the bridging-header to all your targets in the _Build Settings_.

Comment: That has got to be the ugliest method signature I've ever seen...

Comment: I have bridging header for one target..not for all target.